# How To Create And Start Docker Container node, detached mode using docker-java

Tags: java, selenium, docker

I want to create and run docker using docker java client. I want running something like this:

```
docker run -d --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-chrome:2.53.0
```

How to implement this command on docker-java client? Here is my code so far:

```
CreateContainerResponse response = dockerClient
                .createContainerCmd("selenium-hub:hub")
                .withName(name)
                .withImage("selenium/"+browser+":"+version)
                .withAttachStderr(false)
                .withAttachStdin(false)
                .withAttachStdout(false)
                .exec();
```

Actually IDK how to specify --link. please help me. sorry I am new in Docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version do you use of docker-java? I tried the current version (3.0.8) and there is a `withLinks` method for container creation. You can find an example on the [github page](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/dockerjava/core/command/StartContainerCmdImplTest.java).
Keep in mind, that you have to pull those images (`docker pull <imageName>`) before you can create a container using that image.

Example from test:

```
CreateContainerResponse container1 = dockerClient
        .createContainerCmd("busybox")
        .withCmd("sleep", "9999")
        .withName("container1")
        .exec();
dockerClient.startContainerCmd(container1.getId()).exec();
...
CreateContainerResponse container2 = dockerClient
        .createContainerCmd("busybox")
        .withCmd("sleep", "9999")
        .withName("container2")
        .withLinks(new Link("container1", "container1Link"))
        .exec();
dockerClient.startContainerCmd(container2.getId()).exec();
```

The code to match your `docker run` command should look like this I think:

```
CreateContainerResponse container2 = dockerClient
        .createContainerCmd("selenium/node-chrome:2.53.0")
        .withLinks(new Link("selenium-hub", "hub"))
        .exec();
dockerClient.startContainerCmd(container2.getId()).exec();
```

Comment: thank you :) it works in here, well I just update to that version and boom. it work. Thanks a lot